# Does Axios handle the conversion of the response body to responseType in client or does the server handle it?

Tags: javascript, http, axios

I've been reading about `HTTP` headers and read about the `Accept`, from what I read, it is the header which a back-end server uses to know what kind of response that the requesting client expects. I'm curious about what kind of relation it has with the `responseType` option of an Axios request or does it have any at all.

```
// `responseType` indicates the type of data that the server will respond with
// options are: 'arraybuffer', 'document', 'json', 'text', 'stream'
```

Say that I send a `GET` request to some API that I know will respond with a `JSON` body then
I set the `responseType` to `arraybuffer`, does Axios handle that conversion?

```
axios
  .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", {
    headers: { Accept: "application/json" },
    responseType: "arraybuffer",
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the code, the `responseType` just determines how the response body is parsed (or not), it has nothing to do with any headers.

The actual response type is denoted by the [`Content-Type` response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type). The [`Accept` request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) should be evaluated by the server to choose from multiple content types for a resource (if available!) based on the client's preference. See [content negotiation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation) for details.